# Stretched background image of button on the tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with the background image of a button.
The first picture shows the application running on a tablet, the second one when it runs on a mobile.
As you can see, the background image on the tablet is stretched: how can I fix this ?

I put the image with all sizes in the drawable folders

And this is the code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLyt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <rewaya.books.hadithbrowser.widgets.TextViewGaddHaytek
        xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/rewaya.books.hadithbrowser"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dip"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_watermark"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        font:customFont="arabtype.ttf" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/labelstyle"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botton_lessonslearned"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_lessonslearned" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botton_meaning"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_meaning" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: tablet]

[image: mobile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to use wrap_content..

#### Just use this code:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLyt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<rewaya.books.hadithbrowser.widgets.TextViewGaddHaytek
    xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/rewaya.books.hadithbrowser"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detailsText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dip"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
    android:src="@drawable/background_watermark"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    font:customFont="arabtype.ttf" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/labelstyle"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botton_lessonslearned"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_lessonslearned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botton_meaning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_meaning" />


</LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'wrap_parent').

Answer (score 0):

Try `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent` for the `Button` width. It seems that the tablet size is larger than the image size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/labelstyle"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > ...
```

I.e. the width of the bar should be `wrap_content` and `centerHorizontal` should be set to true.

Comment: the size of bar buttons decrease and become in the center

Comment: I thought that was the intended effect. You need to either scale this uniformly or provide alternate resources for the tablet.